# TypeError: .map is not a function - React application

Tags: reactjs, fetch, crud, fetch-api

I created this React application to practice the fetch API.
However, while writing the code to display the data on the browser via the map method, I got the error message "TypeError: profile.map is not a function". Below is the code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  // https://reqres.in/api/users
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const getProfile = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users");
    const data = await response.json();
    setProfile(data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>React fetch</h1>
      <div className="main">
        <section className="section">
          <h2>Get database</h2>
          <div>
            {loading ? (
              <Fragment>loading..</Fragment>
            ) : (
              profile.map(i => {
                <Fragment>
                  <ul>
                    <li>{i.id}</li>
                    <li>{i.email}</li>
                    <li>{i.first_name}</li>
                    <li>{i.last_name}</li>
                    <li>
                      <image src={i.avatar} />
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </Fragment>;
              })
            )}
          </div>
        </section>
        <form className="section">
          <h2>Post data</h2>
          <input type="text" placeholder="enter detail" />
          <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
        <form className="section">
          <h2>Update data</h2>
          <select>
            <option>Choose data</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" placeholder="enter detail" />
          <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why isn't map being recognized?

Comment: Because `data` in `setProfile(data);` is not an array. If you post the response of `data` here in the question, I am sure you would find it out.

Comment: @choz I only have one page in this project and the API is from "https://reqres.in/api/users"

Comment: Have a look at the url you provide closely. That's not an array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's because .map is a method for Array prototypes, not for Objects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You can return the array from the object by using data.data instead of just data:

```
...
  const getProfile = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users");
    const data = await response.json();
    setProfile(data.data); // probably a safer way to do this, but if you console.log(data) you'll see an object is being returned, not an array. 
    setLoading(false);
  };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, `const data = await response.json();` After this line is executed the result we are getting inside the data constant is an Object. We can use MAP function only on Arrays (particularly array prototypes) not on Objects. And also the Profile data which you are actually searching is inside the "data" key of the data "constant". So while setting profile data, just use `setProfile(data.data);`.

A suggestions: [Use this Chrome Extension for viewing the API data. It indents the json objects automatically](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa/related?hl=en)

Answer (score -2):

Map needs to return a value.

```
        {loading ? (
          <Fragment>loading..</Fragment>
        ) : (
          profile.map(i => {
           return (
            <Fragment>
              <ul>
                <li>{i.id}</li>
                <li>{i.email}</li>
                <li>{i.first_name}</li>
                <li>{i.last_name}</li>
                <li>
                  <image src={i.avatar} />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </Fragment>;
            )
          })
        )}
```

Also, you cannot use the map function on an object. It looks like your response is an object, what you are looking for is the data from the response. Try this...

```
setProfile(data.data);
```

Comment: it made no difference

Comment: Array.map does not need a return statement in it. Why do you think that? Remember that OP already has a return statement AROUND the invocation of the map function.